# Error: Linker command failed: duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, linker-errors

Out of nowhere, this error appeared. 
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
duplicate symbol _HighScoreNumber in:
    /Users/Drizzle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Munch-gfdyumgsjgsmdweirrclsqfltxpt/Build/Intermediates/Munch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Munch.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Menu5.o
    /Users/Drizzle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Munch-gfdyumgsjgsmdweirrclsqfltxpt/Build/Intermediates/Munch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Munch.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Gam4.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I fix this?

I looked in the build phase for a duplicate, I tried cleaning the build and rerunning it, I restarted the IOS simulator data.

Comment: Do you have a Menu5.c and Gam4.c?  Is it possible both those files include a common header, and that header *defines* (not declares) `_HighScoreNumber`?

Comment: No, just a .m and .h for both of them. Thank you though!

Comment: I do have "NSInteger HighScoreNumber" in both Menu5.h and Gam4.h. I have HighScoreNumber in Menu5.m and Game4.m so I need to set this variable in both .h's, right?

Comment: Yes, .m I should have said.  And No to the setting in both .h's.  What I was getting at with the header is that the high score should only exist in one place, preferably a source (.m) file.  I say "preferably" because when it's in a header, it could be included in multiple sources, leading to the duplicate symbol error you see.

Comment: What language is this? Please add the relevant tag.

Comment: Judging by the path, it looks like a Mac, the .m file would be Objective-C (IIRC).  But the problem is really about general linking, and less about language.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler's error is clear. There are duplicate symbols within your imported files. You imported `Menu5.h` and `Gam4.h` at the same time, which these two files both contain the definition of `HighScoreNumber`, so compiler is confused.

Remove one if you define repeatedly. Or you could move `HighScoreNumber` definition to a single header file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your solution is to move that variable to your .m file, and remove it from both headers.  If you want to refer to that high score, defined (soon) in a source file, from a second source file, you can declare "`extern int HighScoreNumber;`" in that second source file.